# Check if id attribute already exists in CoreData - Swift 3.0

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8

Suppose I saved the Following Restaurant Details like id, name, address like that in core data , then how can i check wether Restaurant with particular id exist or not in core data data base.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an `NSFetchRequest` for the appropriate entity.
- Assign an `NSPredicate` to the request with format `id == %@, currentID`.
- Perform a fetch.
- If the returned array is not empty the item exists.

Comment: Thank U for Ur Answer